# How to implment drag and drop feature on Rubymotion for a OSX app

Tags: macos, drag-and-drop, rubymotion

Trying to whip up something quick and dirty that mass renames and converts files, and having a rubymotion license I thought why not use it to make a simple app that you can drag and drop instead of some batch file.

However I am having trouble detecting the drag event, can't seem to find information about how to do this in rubymotion, I've only used rubymotion to do iOS apps, and find myself lost.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I haven't done drag+drop in OSX myself, but you might look at Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/DragandDrop.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you started on any Cocoa tutorials?  Anything written in Objective-C can be ported easily.  I would start here: [Drag and Drop Programming (developer.apple.com)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Concepts/dragdestination.html)

If you want to support dragging onto the dock icon, you'll need to modify the project's supported document types, and I'm not sure how to do this (check `rake config`, it might give a clue).  You'll eventually need to implement this method, too:

```
def application(sender, openFile: path)
  # sender is an NSApplication, path is NSString
  true  # or false
end
```

Comment: I forgot that `app.info_plist` is available, so you should be able to add the document types there.  The XML key is `CFBundleDocumentTypes` and `CFBundleTypeExtensions`, e.g. `app.info_plist['CFBundleDocumentTypes'] = [{'CFBundleTypeExtensions'=>['txt'],'CFBundleTypeRole'=>'Editor'}]`

Comment: I got those keys from here: http://qt-project.org/doc/note_revisions/351/659/view

Comment: Thank you for the advice! still having difficulty translating obj-c to ruby, I know it should be high-priority to be able to do that since most of the info for OSX and iOS would be in Obj-C.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add something like :

```
app.info_plist['CFBundleDocumentTypes'] = [
  {'CFBundleTypeRole': 'Viewer', 'CFBundleTypeExtensions': ['mp4','m4v','avi','*'] } ,
  {'CFBundleTypeRole': 'Editor', 'CFBundleTypeExtensions': ['txt'] }
]
```

to the setup block in the `Rakefile`

And add the following method to the AppDelegate class in `app_delegate.rb`

```
def application(sender, openFile: path)
  true
end
```

Do a `rake clean` before you do `rake build` and you should be good to go.

Note that the `application` method gets called for each file that you drop onto the Application icon. `path` contains a string of the dropped files path.